# How to view the XML form of an Excel file?

Tags: xml, excel

How can I view the XML form of an Excel `*.xlsx` file?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

XLSX files are just ZIP files, so unzip them using your favourite ZIP tool.

Answer (score 26):

The following procedure worked for me:

1. Change the extension of the file from .xlsx to .zip
2. Unzip with winzip

Answer (score 6):

You can do this easily using the `tar` command:

`tar -xf pathtofile\excel_file.xlsx`

This works on Windows 10 and Linux

Comment: If you are on windows, 7-ziip does a very good job of this from explorer with no need to get open up a git-bash terminal or windows console.    If it's installed, right click the xlsx file and select from the 7-zip options.  Just, FYI for any readers who come across your solution.