# How can I get Encoding of an Excel file in C# ? it always returns "Windows 1252"

Tags: c#, excel, encoding, utf-8

```
if (bom[0] == 0xef && bom[1] == 0xbb && bom[2] == 0xbf) // BOM Check 
{
    encodingType = Encoding.UTF8;// UTF8  Returns
}
```

**I saved file as UTF8 Encoding, But this part is being skipped always**

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235189/how-can-i-determine-the-character-encoding-of-an-excel-file

Comment: I think that is not specific for any C# code.@Corak

Comment: What kind of file do you save using UTF-8 encoding? CSV? And how do you do this? Hint: For UTF-8 the BOM is not required. So most programs will not put a BOM there by default.