# Excel crashes on opening 6mb file which has lots of objects

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2007

I copy-pasted content from webpages into an Excel file in various sheets.

Saving the file took a long time and I realised that the file size had grown to 6mb.

When I open the file Excel crashes.

Is there any way to remove all objects through VBA from some other Excel file or a suggestion how I can solve this issue?

Comment: You can view the xml structure of an XLSX by [converting it to a ZIP archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984254/how-to-view-the-xml-form-of-an-excel-file). Look for the images in: `/xl/media/`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. `/xl/media/` contains only 1 file of 1kb but `\xl\activeX\` folder contains 20,163 files of size 4.47 mb, `\xl\drawings\` folder contains 12 files of size 2.85 mb and `xl\worksheets` folder contains 12 files of size 2.50 mb any suggestion?

Comment: Start removing files from `\xl\activeX`? (I assumed the content that bloated the file so much was images). Do I need to add you should work on a copy of the file?

Comment: haha.. i was working on copy of the file anyways. I tried your solution, deleted all activex file, converted back to `.xlsx` and tried opening the file. Initially I got error `Excel found unreadable content in x.xlsx. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.` I clicked Yes and atleast I was able to open the file. Deleted all objects and now the file size is 222kb. Thank you so much. God bless !

Comment: btw. you can answer the question so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the xml structure of an XLSX by [converting it to a ZIP archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984254/how-to-view-the-xml-form-of-an-excel-file).

Look for the images in: /xl/media/

As mentioned in your comment, ActiveX content is in `\xl\activeX`