# Convert xlsx Files to plain xml format?

Tags: excel, xml, xlsx

Is it possible to convert xlsx files into a plain XML Format, which can be opened by a text editor?

It seems that xlsx Files are in a compressed or binary format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view the XML form of an Excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984254/how-to-view-the-xml-form-of-an-excel-file)

Comment: Yes, thank you! So xlsx is in fact a zip file! I somehow had in mind that it could also be a big single xml file. Maybe this was the case in earlier versions?